# CodeIgniter echo render_input change label?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am currently seeking some help in changing the labels on a CodeIgniter based project. Here my code which renders out the fields as well as labels directly:

```
     <?php $value=( isset($client) ? $client->address : ''); ?>
     <?php echo render_textarea( 'address', 'client_address',$value); ?>
     <?php $value=( isset($client) ? $client->city : ''); ?>
     <?php echo render_input( 'city', 'client_city',$value); ?>
     <?php $value=( isset($client) ? $client->state : ''); ?>
     <?php echo render_input( 'state', 'client_state',$value); ?>
     <?php $value=( isset($client) ? $client->zip : ''); ?>
     <?php echo render_input( 'zip', 'client_postal_code',$value); ?>
```

On the frontend this renders as follows:

```
   <div class="form-group" app-field-wrapper="city">
   <label for="city" class="control-label">City</label>
   <input type="text" id="city" name="city" class="form-control" value="Test">
   </div>
```

For instance I would like to change State to be Province and perhaps add some formatting. What would be the correct way to have this changed / done in CodeIgniter? Some expert help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 possibilities :

1. Change the lang file concerned, the variable to change is `client_state`
2. Change this line

```
echo render_input( 'state', 'client_province',$value);
```

But keep in mind you have to add this new variable (`client_province`) in your custom lang file.
And, that change would continue to use the State field in the database.

The best way would be to add a custom field named province in client view maybe?